# How can I look at the final code generated by the macros in Parity Substrate?

Tags: blockchain, substrate

Substrate uses a lot of macros to make it easier to write runtime modules:

- `construct_runtime!`
- `decl_module!`
- `decl_storage!`
- `decl_event!`
- etc...

However, it is hard to understand what these macros actually do and what the final code looks like. How can I dig deeper into these macros and expansions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me, the most comfortable solution is to use `cargo expand`

https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand

```
cargo install cargo-expand
```

then just call it from your crate

```
cargo expand
```

Comment: Hm, isn't `cargo expand` only works for nightly? If so, I think you should specify the `+nightly`. (As well as installing cargo-expand for a nightly toolchain)

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to take a look at the final generated code for a crate, you can run the following:

```
cargo +nightly rustc --profile=check --package <crate-name> --lib -- -Zunstable-options --pretty=expanded > <output-file>
```

Note there are two variables here: `<crate-name>` and `<output-file>`.

Thus, if you wanted to look at your final runtime from the substrate-node-template, you would run:

```
cargo +nightly rustc --profile=check --package node-template-runtime --lib -- -Zunstable-options --pretty=expanded > substrate-node-template-runtime.rs
```

Or if you wanted to look at just the expansion of a single module like the Sudo module, you could do:

```
cargo +nightly rustc --profile=check --package srml-sudo --lib -- -Zunstable-options --pretty=expanded > sudo-module.rs
```

These would produce files with all the expanded code that look like this: https://gist.github.com/shawntabrizi/b4a1952dbd3af113e8a3498418e52741