# How do we use topics in events?

Tags: substrate

I am trying to use `deposit_event_indexed` [method](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/pre-v2.0-3e65111/src/frame_system/lib.rs.html#549-590) when depositing an event with a specific topic so that I can use something like the polkadot.js' [api.query.system.eventTopics](https://polkadot.js.org/api/substrate/storage.html#eventtopics-hash-vec-blocknumber-eventindex) to fetched indexed events.

However, I get the following error

```
63  | |  Self::deposit_event_indexed(&eventHashArray, RawEvent::TestIndexedEvent());
    | |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `Module<T>`
```

I am also quite new to rust, so from my understanding, according to the doc, this method is part of the Module's trait. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are calling `deposit_event_indexed` from your custom pallet, you simply need to target the function which is located in the `frame_system` pallet.

```rust
frame_system::Module::<T>::deposit_event_indexed(...)
```

Unlike the more commonly used `deposit_event` feature, we do not automatically import this into your pallet, which is why you see this error.

Comment: Do you mind pointing out where I can see what is being imported for future use? thanks!

Comment: @littlelilo it is honestly a little hard to point out exactly, since Substrate macros do things which you do not see until compile time. Take a look at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705298/how-can-i-look-at-the-final-code-generated-by-the-macros-in-parity-substrate/56705299#56705299