# Converting Enum RawEvent into associated type Event in deposit_event

Tags: substrate

I would like to use the `deposit_event_indexed` method in a module but running into a problem.

Building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60720925/how-do-we-use-topics-in-events), I would like to deposit `MyEvent` which has generics.

```
system::Module::<T>::deposit_event_indexed(&[eventHash], RawEvent::MyEvent(id, time).into());
```

However, I am unable to convert the RawEvent Enum into the Event type like it is done [here](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/pre-v2.0-3e65111/src/frame_system/lib.rs.html#541) because of this error:

```
the trait `std::convert::From<RawEvent<_, <T as pallet_timestamp::Trait>::Moment>>` is not implemented for `frame_system::Event`
```

---

EDITED

Sorry my mistake, I had to create a ::Event *from* the Enum RawEvent  and then *into* ::Event

Comment: So your problem is resolved?

Comment: Yes, it has been resolved with first creating an event `let event = <T as Trait>::Event::from(RawEvent::MyEvent(id, time));` then passing `event.into` to `deposit_event_indexed`

Comment: I would recommend posting an official answer to this question or closing it in that case :)

Answer (score 0):

To use the

`pub fn deposit_event_indexed(topics: &[T::Hash], event: T::Event) { ... }`

The second arg is type `frame_system::Trait::Event`

The module's `Trait::Event` has implemented trait `into()` to convert into `frame_system::Trait::Event`

Therefore we first convert `RawEvent` into `Trait::Event`

```
let event = <T as Trait>::Event::from(RawEvent::MyEvent(id, time));
system::Module::<T>::deposit_event_indexed(&[event_hash], event.into());
```